# Is it possible for a desktop computer to use a laptop's WiFi?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, windows-8.1, ethernet, desktop-computer

Given a curious setup, my desktop computer is now far from an accessible connection to the internet as it lacks WiFi, yet I do have a spare laptop lying around with WiFi capabilities. Is it possible to use the available WiFi connection in my desktop, through the laptop?

I've seen a couple of these questions thus far, but none have been specific to Windows 8.1, the operating system on both computers.

Thanks!

Comment: The laptop would have to have a LAN device in order to do the brdige that AAA talks about.  Many laptops don't have one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - It sounds like what you are trying to do is setup a WiFi bridge using your laptop. Check out this video for a general Windows guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IqKdBj537cg

I would still recommend getting a WiFi adapter for your desktop - you can find USB adapters for